# Replace a list of characters in a string and do not override replaced characters

Tags: c#, encryption, replace

I'm working on this decryption program for a hobby of mine: geocaching.

### The idea

I have a base list of chars :

```
[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

And in a windows form you can specify with which character each character should be replaced.

```
[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]
```

So this would result in my string to decrypt being converted into uppercase.

example: `the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog` would result in `THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG`

### How I solved it

```
public static string DecodeWithKey(string source, string keyBase, string keyValue)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(source);
    for (int i = 0; i < keyBase.Length; i++)
    {
        sb = sb.Replace(keyBase[i], keyValue[i]);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Now this works fine for the above sample. But it completely fails when you start moving characters around.

### The problem is in the order of things

So let's say this is my base again:

```
[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

And now I'm using a bit more realistic values to be replaced:

```
[a,b,c,d,t,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,p,u,v,w,x,y,z,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Notice, I changed e with t and t with p.

The result: `the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog` becomes `php quick brown fox jumps ovpr php lazy dog`

As you can see in `the` it replaced it to `tht` and then to `php`. Which is obvious from my logic.

How can I prevent this? so that is shows `pht` and doesn't replace a character twice.

I hope I have explained it clearly.

Comment: p exists twice in your second sample - if this is correct, it means, it is impossible to restore the original text.

Comment: @Daniel thanks for the angle. This is however only to decrypt a string so it doesn't matter.

Comment: As I said, decrypting is not possible after you encrypted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you simply build the decoded string character by character rather than modifying a copy of the source in-place?

First, build a dictionary that matches each coded char to its decoded value

```
public static string DecodeWithKey(string source, Dictionary<char,char> decoder) 
{ 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(source.Length); 
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++) 
    { 
        sb.Append( decoder[source[i]] ); // error management left out as an exercice
    } 
    return sb.ToString(); 
}
```

In response to Piotr comment, let's try to throw some LINQ into the game:

```
public static string DecodeWithKey(string source, Dictionary<char,char> decoder) 
{ 
    return String.Concat(from ch in source select decoder[ch]);
}
```

Comment: I feel a bit stupid :-) You're right that is so ez. I should go get coffee now...

Comment: Loop can be replaced with LINQ

Comment: I was indeed surprised to see such a question from someone with your reputation. No worries, we all have bad days ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex replace to do what you want. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351031/regex-replace-multiple-groups/).

Convert your replacements to a dictionary, and then:

```
var regex = new Regex(String.Join("|",map.Keys));
var newStr = regex.Replace(str, m => map[m.Value]);
```