# How to replace characters in a string?

Tags: c#, .net, file

I want to replace characters in a string content in file. 
Below Dictionary shows the Key as unwanted character and i need to replace with the value in the Dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, string> unwantedCharacters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        unwantedCharacters["É"] = "@";
        unwantedCharacters["Ä"] = "[";
        unwantedCharacters["Ö"] = "\\";
        unwantedCharacters["Å"] = "]";
        unwantedCharacters["Ü"] = "^";
        unwantedCharacters["é"] = "`";
        unwantedCharacters["ä"] = "{";
        unwantedCharacters["ö"] = "|";
        unwantedCharacters["å"] = "}";
        unwantedCharacters["ü"] = "~";
```

Here is the code i currently using,Feel like its taking too much execution time..

```
 for (int index = 0; index < fileContents.Length; index++)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in unwantedCharacters)
            {
                if (fileContents.IndexOf(item.Key) > -1)
                {
                    fileContents = fileContents.Replace(item.Key, item.Value); // Replacing straight characters
                }
            }
        }
```

ie,Looping in two levels.. Any other ways implement this..Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Why are you looping over `fileContents`? Makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: also, you can drop the `if (fileContents.IndexOf(item.Key) > -1)` check

Comment: Regular expression replace to the rescue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems fileContents is a string value here. You could simply call replace on the string.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in unwantedCharacters)
{
    fileContents = fileContents.Replace(item.Key, item.Value); 
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but is this the same thing using a `foreach`?

Comment: If the replacing characters are not present, it will effectively do nothing. C# is smart enough that it won't do a string copy.

Comment: Iterating through the data, instead of the unwanted chars is much more efficient, which is something  the OP is interested in.

Comment: This is `O(nm)` (length of input, number of characters) when `O(n)` is possible.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're not modifying the length of the string, if you make `unwantedCharacters` a `Dictionary<char, char>` rather than `<string, string>`, you can do the following:

```
var charArray = fileContents.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++)
{
    char replacement;
    if (unwantedCharacters.TryGetValue(charArray[i], out replacement))
        charArray[i] = replacement;
}
fileContents = new string(charArray);
```

Performance is `O(n)` in releation to the length of the input string.

Comment: +1 interesting solution. Never thought about converting file to array of chars. It would be interesting to compare performance of solutions with strings vs chars array

Comment: I think `fileContents` is already a string... just a string read from a file. Performance-wise I'd expect this to be on a par with the `StringBuilder` answer (since that has a fixed length supplied too) but faster than doing anything that involves concatenating or replacing in strings.

Answer (score 2):

Look this answer: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7351142/1848942)

But in this code put your characteres:

```
IDictionary<string,string> map = new Dictionary<string,string>()
    {
       {"É", = "@"},
       {"Ä", = "["},
       {"Ö", = "\\"},
       ...
    };
```

Comment: nice link but i think best place for it is comment

Comment: This is, I think, `O(nm)` (length of input, number of characters) when `O(n)` is possible.

Answer (score 2):

In order to replace many characters in string, consider to use [StringBuilder Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Replacing one character in string causes in creation of entirly new string so it is highly inefficient. Try the below:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(fileContents.Length);

foreach (var c in fileContents)
    sb.Append(unwantedCharacters.ContainsKey(c) ? unwantedCharacters[c] : c);

fileContents = sb.ToString();
```

I assumed here, that your dictionary contains characters (`Dictionary<char, char>`). It it is a case, just comment and I will edit the solution.

I also assumed, that `fileContents` is a string.

You can also use *LINQ* instead of *StringBuilder*:

```
var fileContentsEnumerable = from c in fileContents
                             select unwantedCharacters.ContainsKey(c) ? unwantedCharacters[c] : c;

fileContents = new string(fileContentsEnumerable.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to build a **filter**. You process the contents of the file, and do the substitution while you process it.

Something like this:

```
        using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("filename"))
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("outfile"))
        {
            char currChar = 0;
            while ((currChar = reader.Read()) >= 0)
            {
                char outChar = unwantedCharacters.ContainsKey(currChar)
                                   ? unwantedCharacters[currChar]
                                   : (char) currChar;
                writer.Write(outChar);
            }
        }
```

You can use a memeory stream if your data is in memory, or a loop through `fileContents` is that's a string or char array.

This solution is O(n) where n is the length of the file, thanks to the dictionary (note that you could use a simple sparse array instead of the dictionary and you would gain quite a bit of speed).

**Do not** iterate through the dictionary as other suggest as each substitution is O(n) so you end up with a total time of O(n*d), d being the dictionary size, as you have to go through the file many times.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `foreach` and replace with a `for` loop from 0 to `item.Count`.  [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365615/in-net-which-loop-runs-faster-for-or-foreach) will help, hopefully.

Comment: @Downvoter: Why the down vote?  Please explain.  The user wanted speed, I suspect, at the price of readability, hence my post.