# Insert (single) spaces before and after a specific symbol

Tags: c#, regex

I need to insert (single) spaces before and after a specific symbol (e.g. "|"), like this:

```
string input = "|ABC|xyz |123||999|   aaa|   |BBB";
string output = "| ABC | xyz | 123 | | 999 | aaa | | BBB";
```

This can easily be achieved using a couple of regular expression patterns:

```
string input = "|ABC|xyz |123||999|   aaa|   |BBB";

// add space before |
string pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9\\s*]*\\|";
string replacement = "$0 ";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);

// add space after |
pattern = "\\|[a-zA-Z0-9\\s*]*";
replacement = " $0";
output = Regex.Replace(output, pattern, replacement);

// trim redundant spaces
pattern = "\\s+";
replacement = " ";
output = Regex.Replace(output, pattern, replacement).Trim();

Console.WriteLine("Original String: \"{0}\"", input);
Console.WriteLine("Replacement String: \"{0}\"", output);
```

But that is not what I want, my target is just use a single pattern.

I tried many ways but it still doesn't work as expected. Could anybody help me with this please.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Define "doesn't work as expected".  Do you get nothing back?  The wrong result?  An error?

Comment: No error but wrong output result, for example there are more spaces than necessary (instead of 1 space), that's why I thought about combining a couple of patterns, but is it possible to use just a single pattern to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @Santhosh Nayak.

I just write more C# code to get the output as OP want.

```
string input = "|ABC|xyz |123||999|   aaa|   |BBB";
string pattern = @"[\s]*[|][\s]*";
string replacement = " | ";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, (match) => {
     if(match.Index != 0)
        return replacement;
     else
        return value;
});
```

I refer to [Regex.Replace(string input, string pattern, MatchEvaluator evaluator)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx) in MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
string input = "|ABC|xyz |123||999|   aaa|   |BBB";

string pattern = @"[\s]*[|][\s]*";
string replacement = " | ";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
```

Comment: Thanks, but there are still redundant white spaces between `"|"`, output is `" | ABC | xyz | 123 |  | 999 | aaa |  | BBB"`. If there is no solution, perhaps I have to use one more pattern to remove redundant white spaces.

Comment: @PhongHo I think you can use his regex pattern to get your result. We just write more Regex C# code :) .

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7351142/13198):

```
var str = "|ABC|xyz |123||999|   aaa|   |BBB";
var fixed = Regex.Replace(str, patt, m =>
            {
                if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m.Value))//multple spaces
                    return "";
                return " | ";
            });
```

This returns `| ABC | xyz | 123 |  | 999 | aaa |  | BBB`

We stil have `|(space)(space)|` between `aaa` and `BBB` but that is due to replacement of `|` with `|`.